# Instagram Login

Tags: authentication, instagram-api

I'm new to the Instagram API and I am very interested in using it to create a login for a site I am building as another option for the user to get access. I've had a brief look at the documentation but still have no real understanding on how this could be achieved. Any help/links/documentation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Did you see this documentation?  It is really spot-on so I would recommend taking a look and then if you still have specific questions about it just edit your question and I'll see if I can answer them.

http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/